# Most common name for this kind of image, where the sun illuminates the horizon

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s the most common name for this kind of image?

[image: Sun on horizon]

I want to find other similar images, but I don’t know how to formulate my search request.

Comment: What about the image?  The content?  The aspect ratio?

Comment: Google image search allows you to drag & drop pictures into the search bar to do a visually similar search.  It is, however, rather limited at this time (searching for this image only brings up 4 results).

Comment: Umm, I think you really need to clarify what it is about the image that you want to categorize. Pictures taken from space? Very dark pictures? Pictures that use blurred light for dramatic effect? Pictures that are wider than they are tall? Etc etc.

Comment: @Fisher of cource, I've tried it. It gives nothing. http://goo.gl/1YnXu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides the [space horizon](https://www.google.com/search?q=horizon&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=jXrsT7u6DcKf6AGbrNjPBQ&biw=961&bih=391&sei=j3rsT6KNJuWI6AHEu-XIBQ#q=space+horizon&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=66a600b258da2d38&biw=1003&bih=583) and [space sunrise](https://www.google.ca/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&q=space%20sunrise&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=w3vsT7_uK4XMqgGt_dzvBQ&biw=1920&bih=989&sei=-3vsT8HmJJTpqAGVyfnvBQ#q=space+sunrise&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbm=isch&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1&biw=1504&bih=874) google image searches mentioned previously, [diamond ring eclipse](https://www.google.com/search?q=diamond+ring+eclipse&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=IILsT7WlO8GImQWo-JXuAg&sqi=2&ved=0CEsQsAQ&biw=1003&bih=583) and [Baily's beads](https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=Baily%27s+beads&oq=Baily%27s+beads&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24.1553.1553.0.4294.1.1.0.0.0.0.261.261.2-1.1.0...0.0.OopkZ7BjkEw&biw=1003&bih=583&sei=ooPsT9yFMMmu2AWDwrWxAQ) may be useful to look for.  (Granted, if you want some illuminated planet surface to be visible, *space sunrise* seems to be the proper thing to look for.)

As noted in dictionary.reference.com, *[diamond ring effect](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diamond+ring+effect)* refers to

> a phenomenon, sometimes observed immediately before and after a total eclipse of the sun, in which one of Baily's beads is much brighter than the others, resembling a diamond ring around the moon.

The [Baily's beads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_ring_effect) article in wikipedia explains the  diamond ring effect at more length, and also notes:

> The name is in honor of Francis Baily who first provided an exact explanation of the phenomenon in 1836.  The diamond ring effect is seen when only one bead is left; a shining diamond set in a bright ring around the lunar silhouette.

Answer (score 4):

Space Sunrise seems to fit the bill better than Space Horizon. [Space Sunrise: Google Image Search](https://www.google.ca/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&q=space%20sunrise&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=w3vsT7_uK4XMqgGt_dzvBQ&biw=1920&bih=989&sei=-3vsT8HmJJTpqAGVyfnvBQ)

NASA seems to support this terminology as well. [NASA Space Sunrise Picture With Description](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_385.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look for "globe horizon", "sun rise edge", "atmospheric sunrise", "sun atmosphere line"... these should you provide you some similar images.